# Include a php file without displaying its contents

Tags: php

Is it possible to include a php file without including its contents? I just want to access the functions and variables in that file without displaying any content. I tried this

```
<?
    ob_start();
    include('$file');
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```

But this will hide only contents in php tag. I want to know how to hide others as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I totally agree with Peter's answer

I just tried this because I've never tried it before..

File `toinclude.php`:

```
<p>Loads of text</p>
<?php
    function my_test()
    {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
?>
<a href="doesntmatterwhere.php">Ooh a link</a>
```

File `includer.php`:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('toinclude.php');
    ob_end_clean();
    my_test();
?>
```

And it does work!

Output:

```
Hello
```

Answer (score 7):

How to hide? Redesign your solution and separate your concerns! Do not mix logic with UI and so on.

Maybe you should apply the MVC or similar pattern(s).

Answer (score -1):

No you can't.

Include is meant to execute everything inside the file, there are no ways to prevent execution of some part of the file.
The only way is to edit the included file.

Answer (score -2):

If your file is not printing any output You may try `eval($fileContent)`.

Comment: Sure, it is. But we assume that he'll insert code that is not affected by user input ;) (Or he'll do a nice filtering)

Comment: And it is also slow. Beside that the question indicates that the current code design is bad so with eval it could have really bad side effects for the actual control flow.